# Visiting Rocamadour, France by train

Tags: trains, france

Is Rocamadour rail station near the city centre? Can I go to visit Rocamadour by train, or do I need a car for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may have worked out, Rocamadour the town and Rocamadour the station are separate entities.  In fact, they're about 3-4km apart, depending on whether you trust [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Rocamadour-Padirac) or [other websites](http://www.lourdes-fr.com/en/shrines/rocamadour.htm).

[Wikitravel points out](http://wikitravel.org/en/Rocamadour) that there's only one road in and out of the town.

Arguably then, since it's only 3-4km away, you could get off the train, walk 200m north along La Gare road, and look to hitch west along the D673 road into town.  Or just walk it - it's only 3-4km, and shouldn't take you more than an hour with bags.  There may even be taxis from the station - the trains won't come that often, and the taxi drivers will be aware that people need a ride, and perhaps you could share a cab with someone else getting off the train or even get a ride with them, if they're going into town.

So to answer your question - as long as you're happy 'winging it' once you get there, and are possibly prepared to walk for a little while in the French countryside, then yes, it's totally possible to visit by train.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I've contacted the tourist office, and they confirmed there are taxies only.

Comment: you could post that as an answer, if you like!